# I am unbale to install the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator in my machine

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I downloaded and launched the Setup file for Wso2 and it started downloading all the directories. It is showing a message like

> All products downloaded Successfully

but the window is still open (for about 5 hours) and I can't find any relevant Directories in the Directory path.

[image: Screenshot of Installing]

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the downloader.
Try direct downloading using the link:

https://wso2.com/integration#download